Dynamically resolve FastAPI dependencies on kafka consumer handlers
I have a kafka consumer in a dataclass where I use the kafka producer and the consumer custom decorator (to register the class functions in the consumer class) in order to be able to reuse existing functions and automatically initializing the class and resolving all the FastAPI dependencies dynamically (for now I have two butI will have more). I wonder if there is a way to do that?
Code example:
@dataclass
class UserService:
    producer: Annotated[KafkaProducer, Depends(get_producer)]
    repository: UserRepository = field(default=Depends(get_session))

    async def get_user(self, user_id: str):
        return await self.repository.get_by_id(user_id=user_id)

    @kafka.produce(topic="user-deleted")
    async def delete(self, user_id: str):
        // do something
        await self.producer.produce(topic="user-deleted", key=user.id, value={"id": user.id})

    @kafka.consume(topic="user-deleted", group_id="user-group")
    async def _user_deleted_event(self, event) -> None:
        // do something
        // need to have here an instance of the class and resolved dependencies to have access to self.get_user(user_id=event.id)

I found an approach to use the solve_dependencies of FastAPI util on my consumer class before calling the _user_deleted_event handler but I'm wondering if there is an alternative way. Thanks.
